# Android activity over default lock screen- Android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

How can I display an Activity to be visible over the lock screen/ allow my app to open over the lockscreen when the app is dragged up from a quick placement on  but go back to lockscreen when home button is hit? Sort of how the camera does not need a password to be accessed from the lockscreen?

My activity is visible after I unlock the device.

I have tried using

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

and have set the required permissions in the manifest however this doesn't seem to be working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in normal way.
The Camera App is System App. you cannot even change that option.
unless you use custom ROM like Lineage OS that allow to customize system more. However you will be able to change lock screen shortcuts to your app nothing more.
At least this is my knowledge. 
Good luck

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I thought this may be the case however was being hopeful. Thanks anyway. I might look more into custom ROM's and see if that will work. Thanks again